# Rails - Modeling Like Objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oop, model

Rails novice here. I'm trying to create an application to display information about soccer matches. I have a `Game` model which is meant to contain information about a match. One type of information I would like to include in a `game` object is the events that occur in the match, such as goals and disciplinary actions.

```
class Game < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :events
end
```

What is the best way to model these events? Should there be just one `Event` model or is there any advantage to creating multiple models extending `Event` such as `Goal`, `YellowCard`, `RedCard`, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like an EventType model:

```
# game.rb
class Game < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :events
end

# event.rb
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :event_type
end

# event_type.rb
class EventType < ApplicationRecord
end
```

In the `events` table you could store information such as time/notes, and there would be a field `event_type_id`. In the`event_types` table you can store actions such as goal, yellow_card etc.

You would then easily be able to make queries such as finding all goals in a specific match etc.

Comment: Hadn't thought of this, but I like the idea. Is there any good way to account for the varying attributes that an `event` object will need dependent on the `event_type` to which it belongs?

Answer (score -1):

One suggestion to get you started.

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :teams
  has_many :players, through: :teams
  has_many :goals
  has_many :cards
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :players
end

class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :team
  has_many :cards
  has_many :goals
end

class Card < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :player
  belongs_to :game
end

class Goal < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :player
  belongs_to :game
end
```

*obs: You may want to add a TeamLineup model, as a team can have different lineups depending on the game. I know you asked about events, but I think the proposed solution above, models a soccer game better